# getting datatables error, can't figure out why : TypeError: d[i] is undefined & TypeError: b.nTableWrapper is null

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

We use jQuery DataTables plug in across our app and it works pretty well. However we're encountering an error when we try load up the plug in with mock data (services aren't ready yet) in a modal on the page. We get the following errors ( the 2nd one happens after you click the link again to open the modal)

> TypeError: d[i] is undefined
>
> TypeError: b.nTableWrapper is null

The code looks correct, so I can't figure it out. Anyone with experience on this error ? We built the table map to correspond with the sample data nodes - and we've also tried maps with current working ones to no avail. (They are separated by purpose).

I've added the HTML in the fiddle. But basically it's just a simple table with the ID - the other datatables across the site work just fine with the same structure. Just stumped.

```
var sampleData = [{
        "approvable": true,
        "id": 4938,
        "order_number": "3948948392893",
        "order_template": "AJHSFJKHAS-SDJAS",
        "size": "45mb",
        "size_sort": 4500,
        "ad_type": "testadtype",
        "production_status": "yep!"
    }
];

var makeCampaignApproveModal = function () {

    var $approveParams;
    var $approveComments = $('#approveComments');
    var $approveCampaignForm = $('#approveCampaignForm');
    var $campaignApprove = $('#campaignApprove');
    var $approveCampaignHeader = $campaignApprove.children('h3');
    var $ratingStars = $('#ratingStars');
    var $ratingStar = $('.ratingStar');
    var $ratingApproveCampaign = $('#ratingApproveCampaign');
    var $ratingCancelCampaign = $('#ratingCancelCampaign');

    var init = function () {

        makeCampaignBulkOrders(sampleData);

        //bindings
        $ratingStar.mouseover(function (e) {
            var $this = $(this);
            $this.prevAll().addClass('active');
            $this.nextAll().addClass('inactive');
        });
        $ratingStar.mouseout(function (e) {
            var $this = $(this);
            $this.prevAll().removeClass('active');
            $this.nextAll().removeClass('inactive');
        });

        $ratingStar.on("click", function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var $this = $(this);
            //style prevs
            $this.addClass('selected');
            $this.prevAll().addClass('selected');
            $this.nextAll().removeClass('selected');
            $ratingStars.data('rating', $this.attr('rel'));

        });

        $ratingApproveCampaign.on("click", function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var approveHandler = Portal.Details.synchronousRatingHandler;
            utils.makeProxyCall((actionQueryPath + '/proof/approve'), approveHandler, Portal.Details.proofReturnE);

            callInProgress();
            return false;
        });

        $ratingCancelCampaign.on("click", function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $campaignApprove.modality('close');
        });

        $campaignApprove.addClass('initted');
    }; //init

    if (!$campaignApprove.hasClass('initted')) {
        init();
    }

    aep.utils.setupForm($approveCampaignForm, true, false);
    $ratingStars.data();
    $ratingApproveCampaign.text($l(2019));
    $approveCampaignHeader.html($l(2018) + '<span class="actionModalObjectNumber"></span>');

    updateModalHeader($campaignApprove);

    var curRating = actionDetails['rating'];
    $ratingStar.each(function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        if ($this.attr('rel') <= curRating) {
            $this.addClass('selected');
        } else {
            $this.removeClass('selected');
        }
    });
    $ratingStars.data('rating', curRating);
    $campaignApprove.modality(modalConfig);

};

var makeCampaignBulkOrders = function (coData) {
    var $campaignBulkOrders = $('#campaignBulkOrders');
    var $campaignBulkOrdersTable = $('#bulk-ords-table');
    var DTConfig = {
        'bDestroy': true,
        'bAutoWidth': true,
        'iDisplayLength': -1,
        'bPaginate': false,
        'sScrollY': '200px',
        'bScrollCollapse': true,
        'oLanguage': {
            'sSearch': $l(1024)
        }
    };

    var coData = sampleData || [];
    var coMap = getTableMapBulkOrders();
    var cDTConfig = DTConfig;
    cDTConfig['aaData'] = coData;
    cDTConfig['aaColumns'] = coMap;
    cDTConfig['aaSorting'] = [[1, 'desc']];
    cDTConfig['sScrollY'] = '';
    cDTConfig['bScrollCollapse'] = false;
    $campaignBulkOrders.find('.tableLoading').hide();
    $campaignBulkOrdersTable.dataTable(cDTConfig).fnDraw();
    cDTConfig['aaSorting'] = [];
};

var getTableMapBulkOrders = function () {
    return [{
            oid: 'approvable',
            'sTitle': '',
            'mDataProp': function (source, type, val) {
                if (type == "display") {
                    return '<input type="checkbox" class="campaign-order-approval" rel="' + source.id + '" />';
                }
                return source.id;
            },
            'sClass': 'checkbox'
        },
        {
            oid: 'order_number',
            'sClass': 'order_number',
            'mDataProp': function (source, type, val) {
                var ordNumber = '<a class="detailsLink" href="/portal/details/#orders/' + source.id + '">' + source.order_number + '</a><a href="" title="' + $l(2092) + '" class="orderActionsLink" rel="' + source.id + '"></a>';
                if (type == 'display') {
                    return ordNumber;
                }
                return source['order_number'];
            },
            'sTitle': $l(2089),
            'sClass': 'orderNumber'
        },
        {
            oid: 'order_template',
            'mDataProp': 'order_template',
            'sTitle': $l(2048),
            'sClass': 'order_template'
        }, {
            oid: 'fileSize',
            'mDataProp': function (source, type, val) {
                if (type == "sort") {
                    return source['size_sort'];
                }
                return source['size'];
            },
            'sTitle': $l(2099),
            "sType": "numeric",
            'sClass': 'file_size'
        },
        {
            oid: 'ad_type',
            'mDataProp': 'ad_type',
            'sTitle': $l(2045),
            'sClass': 'ad_type'
        }, {
            oid: 'production_status',
            'mDataProp': 'production_status',
            'sTitle': $l(2097),
            'sClass': 'production_status'
        }
    ];
};
```

jsfiddle is over [here](https://jsfiddle.net/eshans/f442bbps/4/)

Comment: That fiddle isn't much help - where is the HTML and the external resources?  Have you checked that the table exists before you attempt to initialize it?

Comment: hi, thanks. I've added the html to the fiddle.  It follows the same structure as the others, it's just that this one isn't rendering.